# Question about pseudo-replication

Tags: experiment-design

I would like to examine the inter-individual variation in foraging duration by a small seabird species (a storm petrel). I sampled small petrels in their burrows on a small island, and using telemetry devices I have quantified the time that birds spent away from the colony on foraging trips. However due to sampling and logistical constraints, I sometimes had to put devices on both individuals of a breeding pair in the same burrow (i.e. both the male and female of a pair were tagged), whereas in other burrows only 1 bird was tagged. However, including both birds from a single burrow in the overall analysis would be pseudo-replication, as the foraging duration of one bird in a burrow could be influenced by that of the other bird. So to avoid this, I was going to exclude the second bird tagged from those burrows with two tagged birds. However, someone suggested that I take an average of foraging duration from the two birds, and that this averaging would avoid pseudo-replication. I have looked to the literature and books to see if this is a valid approach but I could not find a clear answer.  Can anyone comment on this? Thank you. RAM

Comment: Can you be more specific than "examine the inter-individual variation in foraging duration"? I'd guess that you want more than just an estimate of the variance in foraging duration between individuals. For example, do you want to predict foraging duration as a function of some other variables?

Comment: Yes - thank you. The aim is to explore variation in foraging duration relative to predictor variables like sea surface temperature, Chl-a concentrations and other oceanographic factors.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach in biostatistics would be to use a mixed model with a per-pair random intercept. This accounts for the within-pair dependency (which is what I believe you mean by "pseudo-replication"). You can include the other predictor variables in the model as fixed effects.